# .NET Core HTML Form not binding to controller and action which should return a new View

Tags: razor, .net-core

I have been staring at this problem for a few days now and still I can't understand what's going on. It's probably something really trivial but I can't find the correct assistance on existing questions.
I have the following Razor Html:

```
<div class="modal-body">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Study", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label>question</label>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label><input type="radio" name="Mhd" value="1"> Yes</label><br />
                            <label><input type="radio" name="Mhd" value="0"> No</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label>What is your Gender</label>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label><input type="radio" name="Gender" value="1"> Male</label><br />
                            <label><input type="radio" name="Gender" value="0"> Female</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label for="age">Age:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="Age" id="age">
                            @for (int count = 16; count <= 130; count++)
                            {
                                <option>@(count)</option>
                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcRHE0UAAAAALRTlf_wvx2Si6VxU7oZS3mCfyqS"></div>
                <br />
                <button type="submit" value="Index" class="btn btn-primary float-right" data-dismiss="modal">Start</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn float-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            }
        </div>
```

My controller will be doing something more complex but in the meantime, i am just trying to bind to the following action in a different controller called StudyController.cs :

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    { return View(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the reason, i left `data-dismiss="modal"` in the "Start" button, this was causing the form not too submit.